# SKView loading in wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

so I am trying to create a button that leads the user back to the main menu after the game ends. Everything seems to be set up right, as in the transition works and the scene loads, but the only problem is that the view loads with its center in the bottom left corner. I think the problem is that when I am positioning things in one view the reference point (sorry I don't know the actual term) is in the bottom left corner, and the other view the reference is in the center. I just don't know how to resolve the issue. Here is the code.

```
else if backButton.contains(location) {
    if view != nil {
    let transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
        let scene:SKScene = MenuScene(size: self.size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check anchor point of sks files you are using for scenes. It should be 0.5, 0.5. Rather than 0.0, 0,0. If you are not using sks files, change anchorPoints directly in the code.